# Unable to boot Windows7 or Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

So I'm a total noob to Ubuntu. And I'm have a really bad experience.
Hope you can help with my problem.

My problem is that I had Windows 7 originally installed in my laptop.
So i decide to install Ubuntu because of my IT course the professor wants the class to use and learn Linux.

So I installed it with my usb Ubuntu 16.04.
It worked fine I installed it with the option *Install along with Windows 7*.
But after I installed successfully I wasn't able boot windows 7. So I sticked with Ubuntu and tried to find a solution.

So I looked up lots of ways, on how to fix my probblem, here on ask Ubuntu.
And one answer said to do this. On the repair computer option, prompt command:

1.bootrec.exe/FIXMbr   **Than I did**   2.bootrec.exe/FixBoot

After doing that I still can't boot up Win 7 nor can I boot Ubuntu(because the Grub option to select Ubuntu doesn't appear.

I keep getting the:
Windows can't boot up because of changes in hardware/software.

So I'm unable to boot either one of the OS systems
I am now using the Try Ubuntu without installing, option.

I tried to install win 7 again but I found this when trying to install.

[I found this when I went to install windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnssl.jpg)

Disk 0  Partition 1:Reserved by system.    Type:System

Disk 0  Partition 2:Primary.     Type:primary

Disk 1  Partition 1:MultiBoot .    Type:system

So can I possibly still use Ubuntu or Windows 7?
Or are they both deleted?

Thanks, Sorry if my English ain't so good.         :)

Comment: Don't touch Windows anymore, please. You might dig yourself deeper. Instead, try using `boot-repair`(Google it).

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
Do not attempt any fixes until someone has reviewed the link/report and makes suggestions. It can make things worse even though in most cases it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Default in 16.04 grub menu set is hidden but you can access it by holding shift key on the keyboard after your machine opening screen pass(the menu entering the bios settings).If the ubuntu boots, then  login into ubuntu then you only need to set windows in grub menu.But before check your hardisk with  the program named "disk"(hit superkey-key or click ubutu logo in launcher and type disk)if the windows partition is in sda1 then Open terminal type "sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom" and paste the following into the editor:

menuentry "Windows 7" {

insmod part_msdos

insmod ntfs

set root='(hd0,msdos1)'

chainloader +1

}

save and close and type into terminal "sudo update-grub" now you can see it in grub menu with holding shift key.ıf the windows partition appear in sda2 change line "set root='(hd0,msdos2)'" and so on(sda1->msdos1,sda2 ->msdos2).If you can't boot in ubuntu then start your machine with ubuntu dvd and check your windows partition with "files"(nautilus file manager,second icon in launcher).Copy your important files into a usb disk in Ubuntu.